# Error code 400 when requesting backend with OkHttp3, Chrome returns 200 OK

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp, http-status-code-401, http-status-code-400

I'm in a situation where I need to connect to my backend and get the response. I set up  an interceptor to put in my credentials before sending the request.

```
  val credential: String = Credentials.basic("user123", "myPassword")

  override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
  val originalRequest = chain.request()
  val requestWithUserAgent = originalRequest.newBuilder()
    .addHeader(AUTHORIZATION, credentials)
    .build()
  
  return chain.proceed(requestWithUserAgent)
}
private const val AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization"
```

In this case, I receive **error** **code** **400** and no body. However, when I try the same with a web navigator (Chrome), I'm authorized and have access and I can see the response.

Any other form I tried to log in (Base64) or smth else returns **error code 401**. And in the header : Www-Authenticate: Basic realm="My realm".

What can the issue be here ? What should I add to my android request in the header ?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say what the problem is. But you can compare raw requests(headers + response body).

You can capture traffic from you phone via Fiddler/Charles or another software and see different between raw requests(one made from your phone another one via Chrome). Maybe you forget about some header or parameter in the request body or something else.

How to launch fiddler on the device:
https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-capture-android-traffic-with-fiddler

Comment: Thanks, your comment helped find a way, I posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference. The problem was a missing Accept Header.

```
 val requestWithUserAgent = originalRequest.newBuilder()
   .addHeader(AUTHORIZATION, credentials)
   .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
   .build()
```

Adding it will fix the issue.